# Its possible to a const implements a interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

#### How to force a const type and still get correct values(not type)

###### i.e: "#000000" not string

I have this interface and this type

```
interface IColor {
  base: string
  lighten1?: string
  lighten2?: string
  lighten3?: string
  darken1?: string
  darken2?: string
  darken3?: string
}

type Color = IColor | string
```

What i want to achieve:

```
export const DARK: Color = {
  base: '#000000',
  lighten1: '#212121',
  someRandomProp: '#FFF' -> throws a error
}

const test = DARK.base -> shows '#00000' instead of string
```

Comment: Similar (with a possible solution/workaround): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276320/how-can-treat-string-as-string-literal-when-mapping-object-in-typescript

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve? `someRandomProp` will not compile because it is not a `Color` and `console.log(Dark.base)` should already log `#000000`. Would you like to be able to add a random prop to the object?

Comment: @axtck the way the const its current typed <Color>, its the behavior i want ( throws a erro to someRandomProp ). But it refers to `Dark.base` as string, not #000000. If I remove the type <Color>, `Dark.base` will refer to #000000, but will allow any prop, witch its not acceptable. What i want its to safe guard const type and correctly show the value `Dark['prop'] = Color`, not string

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, good luck on finding an answer!

Comment: @axtck Thank you for your help! I dont understand why something this simple, its so complex to implement with Typescript

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a type for a constant, it must only specify the properties in the type unless if they are in other parts of a non-discriminated union but that is usually not important.  However, TypeScript is duck typed, therefore you can still just use `as const` to make your string literals types work as you expect them for the `DARK` object and remove the type annotation.  Then, create a new constant with an explicitly stated type of `IColor` and assign it to the value of `DARK`.  This will assert that `DARK` is assignable to `IColor` but you will not get errors for when there are extra properties specified.

```
interface IColor {
  base: string
  lighten1?: string
  lighten2?: string
  lighten3?: string
  darken1?: string
  darken2?: string
  darken3?: string
}

type Color = IColor | string

export const DARK = {
  base: '#000000',
  lighten1: '#212121',
  someRandomProp: '#FFF',
} as const;
// { readonly base: "#000000"; readonly lighten1: "#212121"; readonly someRandomProp: "#FFF"; }


const _expectDARKIsColor: Color = DARK; // correctly passes

// FAILING EXAMPLE - no base

export const DARK2 = {
  // base: '#000000',
  lighten1: '#212121',
  someRandomProp: '#FFF',
} as const;

const _expectDARK2IsColor: Color = DARK2; // correctly fails
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2AbTVkDeAsAFDLIBGcAzhAFzLVhSgDmp52wrAFpCAEYA-AyYsQ7Msi69+AJhGNmbDtO58IIAMyKxKqQBM4UANabho5RNVHTmhZfGTyts9t1XJAX1KkwATwAHFCxcfABeNFC8ZAAfJSdfEggAD0C8MGQETBAmZAARAEEAJQBpZEjiKSpaBgByAGIABhbWuoAaVRkNQXqGuQEBgY7VakwAWwhiuBADCYAFKExAvoAxdZGSL2QaLJymAG5SAHpjwmQoCDg5kGx-Shp6ZAAiZtaW54OLq5u7tVlzAxXkNBgJPt9rjk-mNJtNZgslisXg11qtwT4SElsrlMgB9VLBBBgIplVDUaJQBgUioFEqlL6nPZQS5Ev6BGi0ahJRmrQqoAAyqAAcgBxZAAUQAGoUALLzfni5AAWmQIEwD1oSQJGT2ONpZTkNKq5EZNSejXeLU2nHU-AEfRBw06UhhUxmc3Gi2Waw2zu2u2xhyx+zxBIgRJJpTkZIpVJwMUikbkDLO2WZ4bAf3gwGw1CAA)

Comment: Hi @sno2, thanks for the help! This is 'kind of' solution that I wanted. But both `DARK` and `DARK2` should fail on `someRandomProp`, as they are not listed in the `IColor` interface. For now I will follow your advice. I dont understand why something this simple, its so complex to implement with Typescript